# Java Apache HttpClient - Proxy not responding

Tags: java, http, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm experiencing a problem with a simple program using Apache's Java HttpClient in which all requests sent from proxies time out (java.net.ConnectException). I have made sure that all of the proxies in the list work, so that is not the problem. Here's my code:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(ip, port, "http"); // the vars ip and port are taken from the function this is in
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
        "http://www.mysitehere.com"); // And yes, my url works and is not timing out from browser
request.addHeader(
        "User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36");
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,
        proxy);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request); // This code times out.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit:
Example ip and port:

```
"101.96.11.10":"80"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify proxy for each request using `DynamicProxyRoutePlanner` :

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager http
...
        this.http = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        this.http.setMaxTotal(10);
        this.http.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
        this.http.setValidateAfterInactivity(10000);
...
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(ADDRESS, PORT);
DynamicProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DynamicProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(http)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(getRequestConfig(timeout))
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                .build();
...
private static RequestConfig getRequestConfig(int timeout) {
    return RequestConfig.copy( RequestConfig.DEFAULT )
    .setConnectTimeout( timeout )
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout( timeout )
    .setSocketTimeout( timeout )
    .setContentCompressionEnabled( true )
    .setRedirectsEnabled( true )
    .setMaxRedirects( 10 )
    .build();
}
```